# Overview of Arabic fonts available for LaTeX/XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, arabic

Is there an overview available for Arabic fonts in LaTeX / XeTeX?

- Ideally with output examples, so that it becomes clear how they compare.
- So far, I'm aware of

  - Geeza Pro,
  - Amiri (and its variants),
  - Sheherazade and,
  - Al Nile.

But I assume there is much more out there.

Comment: https://ctan.org/topic/arabic

Answer (score 15):

In `texmf-dist/doc/latex/arabi/user_guide.pdf`, pages 50–51 give samples of fonts from Microsoft and from [arabeyes.org](http://arabeyes.org) (there are `.ttf` versions of the latter in Debian’s [fonts-arabeyes](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/fonts-arabeyes) package).  And the documentation for `dad` shows examples of its output.  Of course, with `xetex` and `luatex`, you can use any unicode, OpenType font, whether free or commercial.  Here are some free fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[novoc]{arabluatex}
\linespread{1.25}
\newcommand{\sample}{\arb{الأفكار الخضراء عديمة اللون تنام بغضب}}% http://www.omniglot.com/language/phrases/colorlessgreenideas.htm
\begin{document}
Amiri: \sample% arabluatex defaults to Amiri

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Aref Ruqaa}
Aref Ruqaa: \sample% https://github.com/khaledhosny/aref-ruqaa

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Cairo}
Cairo: \sample% https://github.com/Gue3bara/Cairo

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Hussaini Nastaleeq}
Hussaini Nastaleeq: \sample% https://github.com/khaledhosny/hussaini-nastaleeq

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Jomhuria}
Jomhuria: \sample% https://github.com/khaledhosny/Jomhuria

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Lateef}
Lateef: \sample% http://software.sil.org/arabicfonts/

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Mada}
Mada: \sample% https://github.com/khaledhosny/mada

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Kufi Arabic}
Noto Kufi: \sample% https://www.google.com/get/noto/

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Naskh Arabic}
Noto Naskh: \sample% https://www.google.com/get/noto/

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Reem Kufi}
Reem Kufi: \sample% https://github.com/khaledhosny/reem-kufi

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
Scheherazade: \sample% http://software.sil.org/arabicfonts/
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example]

You can get a list of Arabic fonts available on your computer by typing `fc-list :lang=ar` on the command line, and you can search for [all Arabic Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=arabic).

**Update**: Here’s the brand new [FiraGO](https://bboxtype.com/typefaces/FiraGO/#!layout=specimen), an extension of Fira Sans which adds support for Arabic, Devanagari, Georgian, Hebrew, and Thai to the already impressive range of Fira Sans:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[novoc]{arabluatex}
\newcommand{\sample}{\txarb{الأفكار الخضراء عديمة اللون تنام بغضب}}
\begin{document}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{FiraGO}
FiraGO: \sample% https://github.com/bBoxType/FiraGO
\end{document}
```

[image: FiraGO sample]

**Update two**: Here is the new [Kafa Black](http://arabictype.com/downloads/):

[image: Kafa Black sample]

and its stylistic alternate:

[image: Kafa Black with ss01]

**Update three**: Recently, [IBM Plex Arabic](https://github.com/IBM/plex/tree/master/IBM-Plex-Arabic) has joined the IBM Plex family:

[image: sample of IBM Plex Arabic with calt]

**Update four:** Here’s Aref Ruqaa compiled with [lualatex-dev](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493185):

[image: Aref Ruqaa with Harfbuzz renderer]

**Update five**: Here are Cairo, El-Messiri, and Lemonada, by [Mohamed Gaber](https://github.com/Gue3bara):

[image: Cairo]

[image: El-Messiri]

[image: Lemonada]

**Update six**: [Abd ElRady](https://www.behance.net/gallery/99956001/Abd-ElRady-Free-Typeface-), by AhmED ElqSas:

[image: Abd ElRady]

**Update seven**: As of 5 November 2020, there’s also [Scheherazade New](https://software.sil.org/scheherazade/), which can be installed alongside the older Scheherazade; the new version has resized glyphs:

[image: Scheherazade New]

Comment: Is this LuaTeX? The Ruqaa is completely messed up, the Nastaleeq is a bit messed up as well.

Comment: @KhaledHosny I just downloaded the latest version of those two fonts, recompiled the example, and replaced the image.  No change to the Ruqaa, but the Nastaleeq looks better. (I don’t know whether that’s because of updates to the font or to `arabluatex`.) For anyone who wants to see how the Ruqaa looks in `xetex`, simply replace `\usepackage[novoc]{arabluatex}` with `\usepackage[novoc,utf]{arabxetex}`, and in the `\sample` command, replace `\arb` with `\textarab`.

Comment: The Nastaliq indeed looks better.

Comment: This may yet be related to this issue: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/361

Comment: One tiny bit of advice: with `arabluatex` it's better to type unicode Arabic as argument of the `\txarb{}` command.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to FiraGO which I didn't know, @Thérèse

Comment: When I run your code I get this error **! LaTeX cmd Error: Command '\arabicfont' already defined!**. Why?

Comment: @BlackMath I know. It worked in 2016 when I wrote the original answer, but no longer worked when I added more fonts. I think we have to wait for the author of `arabluatex` to address your question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618286

Comment: @Thérèse I have the documentation for `arabluatex`, and it says we need to load `fontspec` and define the font **before** we load `arabluatex`. When I did this, it worked. However, I want to change between fonts in the document, as you did above

Comment: @RobertAlessi Could you please look at the problem I mentioned above, and let me know how I can fix it?

Comment: @Thérèse and @BlackMath: please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618286#comment1544321_618286) and also [Part II of the documentation of the `fontspec` package](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#e): when a font is defined by means of `\newfontfamily`, `fontspec` now requires `\renewfontfamily` to change it.

Comment: @RobertAlessi Thank you. It's working now

Answer (score 4):

In practical, real-world use, most authors today will save the source in UTF-8, load a TrueType or OpenType Arabic font, and compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.  A list of TrueType or OpenType Arabic fonts would not be specific to TeX or LaTeX. There are a few additions to that list that are worth noting for someone working in LaTeX, however.

### In the Modern Toolchain

Khaled Hosny, the designer of Amiri, also created the Libertinus font family (based on free fonts by Philipp H. Poll), which make excellent companion fonts to Amiri—and, particularly relevant to LaTeX, include an OpenType math font, Libertinus Math.  Hosny also made XITS Math, converted and extended the STIX fonts.  Libertinus and XITS have the best support for Arabic and Persian mathematics of any free font, as well as other features most other math fonts lack, including support for `\boldmath`.  (Dr. Hosny also collaborated on one other OpenType math font, Neo Euler, but it has none of these features and is incomplete.)

Arabic Latin Modern Fixed is a monospaced Arabic font based on Computer Modern, and very suitable for the typewriter font with Babel or Polyglossia.

The Noto family is useful for multilingual documents, as it comes in a number of styles to match other fonts and covers all the world’s scripts.

### Classic Packages

There are some Arabic fonts for legacy packages, which you might still need to compile an old document, and I’ve occasionally still seen in use.  Conventional seven- and eight-bit encodings were never very suitable for Arabic, but the `arabtex` package defined the `xnsh14` pseudo-font, and also supported an older `nash14` pseudo-font, as well as bold variants.  The original sources for these are in METAFONT.  The `farsitex` package is similar.

The `arabi` package offers different local encodings for Arabic and Farsi.  There is a table [in the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/arabic/arabi/arabi/texmf/doc/latex/arabi/user_guide.pdf#section.7.4) of the fonts it supports.  Of these, the Arabeyes Project fonts were also available in a PostScript format.

There were never any other Arabic fonts made specifically for TeX, at least that are still available from CTAN.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Amiri}

\begin{document}
    النص بالعربية
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can start every line with four spaces, so that line-breaks are preserved, and your code appears properly. Also, this answer highlights the “Amiri” font, which is already mentioned in the other answer (and in the question). Was there a reason you posted this?