# Can't write in Arabic in Latex using "arabluatex" package

Tags: arabic, arabtex, arabxetex, arabluatex

I found this [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314202/overview-of-arabic-fonts-available-for-latex-xetex) and followed the first answer. I made this script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[novoc]{arabluatex}
\linespread{1.25}

\begin{document}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Aref Ruqaa}
السلام عليكم

\end{document}
```

But I am getting these errors:

```
Package arabluatex Error: lualatex needed. ... of `arabluatex' for further information.}

Unknown option `novoc' for package `arabluatex'. \linespread

Undefined control sequence. \newfontfamily

Undefined control sequence. \newfontfamily\arabicfont
```

Although I have manually downloaded the package zip file from its [page](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/arabluatex?lang=en) and copied and pasted these files into the same directory where my latex main file is located:

```
-   `arabluatex.sty`
-   `arabluatex-patch.sty`
-   `arabluatex.lua`
-   `arabluatex_voc.lua`
-   `arabluatex_fullvoc.lua`
-   `arabluatex_novoc.lua`
-   `arabluatex_trans.lua`
```

But this did not solve the problem. Can you please help me compile arabic text and be able to use Arabic fonts similar to the script I posted?

I also prefer to not manually paste the package files. Is there any way I can install them within Latex? I use `TexStudio` as editor and it uses `pdflatex` as compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arabluatex` has changed somewhat since the answer you cite, and you’re missing `\txarb{...}`.  Use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[novoc]{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Aref Ruqaa}
\begin{document}
\txarb{السلام عليكم}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

However, you cannot make this package work with `pdftex`; see the [manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a) for setting the compiler to `luatex` in TeXstudio.

(I can’t tell you how to install particular packages, since you don’t say whether you’re using TeX Live or MiKTeX or some other distribution, but there are many questions tagged `installing`, and there’s nothing peculiar about `arabluatex` that would require an unusual method.)

If your heart is set on Aref Ruqaa in particular, output is far better with `lualatex-dev` than with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[novoc]{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Arabic]{Aref Ruqaa}
\begin{document}
\txarb{السلام عليكم}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of second sample]

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493185/ for details on this approach, which requires an up-to-date distribution.

Comment: Thanks. But can you plz. be more secific on what do I need to do to run it with my TexStudio and pdflatex? I opened the link you provided and there is nothing said about `luatex` at all. What should I do plz.?

Comment: @seq you can't run it with pdflatex. Look in the texstudio menus for something that says "lualatex" and use this.

Comment: @seq Look at the ‘Configure TeXstudio’ image.  If you click on the down arrow in the ‘Default Compiler’ line, `LuaLaTeX` should be among the options.  Choose that: you can’t use `arabluatex` with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Thérèse  I did but still can't get your script to run. I posted an edit.

Comment: @Thérèse Also I use ubuntu.

Comment: Your edit should be to your question, not to my answer.  I use Debian, but with the TeX Live from tug.org, not the Debian package.  I don’t know how the Ubuntu packages are structured and which contains `arabluatex`.