# Arabic fonts with justification alternatives

Tags: fonts, babel, arabic, justification

This question is a complement to this other: [Overview of Arabic fonts available for LaTeX/XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314202/overview-of-arabic-fonts-available-for-latex-xetex)

I'm working on Arabic justification for `babel`+`luatex` (see [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/javier_bezos/status/1387742677731524609)) and I'm looking for fonts with the `jalt` OpenType table (justification alternatives). I've found Arabic Typesetting and Sakkal Majalla (it looks like Waseem has it, but it's a Mac font and right now I don't have a Mac at hand).

Do you know any more fonts?

Comment: If you are looking for a justified Arabic font, Arabic Latin Modern Fixed is an important one for LuaTeX/XeTeX.

Comment: @Davislor Nice font, indeed, but sadly it doesn't seem to have the `jalt` feature. Even in the manual justification is done with tatweels and not with elongated glyphs.

Comment: Aref Ruqaa, such as it is, is doing something in the `jalt` space. The only one out of two dozen I checked. Seems a rare feature.

Comment: Among commercial fonts, there’s Sultan Fonts’ [SF Article](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sultan-fonts/sf-article/).

Comment: @Cicada Very helpful. Except for a few bad kerns, what I've done so far seems to work.

Comment: @Thérèse From the specimen I'd say it even supports curvilinear kashida. But I can't afford it. A pity.

Comment: The current documentation of `fontspec` says that `jalt` is to date [unsupported](https://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#page=38).  Is there some other way to use it?

Comment: @RobertAlessi `jalt` is not exactly a font property, but a combination of font and layout engine. With some tricks, I've managed to support it, at least in part, in `babel`, as you can see in the linked Tweet. See also https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/news-guides/news/whats-new-in-babel-3.58.md#arabic-justification-experimental and https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/news-guides/news/whats-new-in-babel-3.59.md .

Comment: [JH Haroun](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jh-fonts/jh-haroun?tab=glyphs) claims “smart Kashidas.”

Comment: A different approach is to use a variable font axis for kashida, as in [Estedad](https://v-fonts.com/fonts/estedad), which is open-source.

Comment: There’s both a project and a font at https://digitalkhatt.org/about

Comment: @Thérèse Wonderful page. I intend to resume the work on the Arabic justification very soon.